# video-js-resolution creates TypeError when multiple videos are drawn

Tags: javascript, video.js

I seem to be getting a TypeError when attempting to draw more then one video while using video.js (ver 4.12.11) plugin video-js-resolution. Of course the first video works fine, but any javascript or any other videos after do not work.

```
TypeError: window.videojs[componentClass] is not a constructor
```

- FireFox

```
Uncaught TypeError: window.videojs[componentClass] is not a function
```

- Google Chrome

On video.dev.js, line (1446):

```
component = new window['videojs'][componentClass](this.player_ || this, options);
```

Here is my test page:

```
<video id="home_video" controls preload="none" poster="http://img05.deviantart.net/aaee/i/2011/105/c/0/nyan_cat_wallpaper_by_nyakiru-d3e1zfl.png" width="970" height="404" class="video-js vjs-default-skin">
  <source src="http://vjs.zencdn.net/v/oceans.mp4?hd" type="video/mp4" data-res="HD" />
  <source src="http://vjs.zencdn.net/v/oceans.mp4?sd" type="video/mp4" data-res="SD" />

  <source src="http://vjs.zencdn.net/v/oceans.webm?hd" type="video/webm" data-res="HD" />
  <source src="http://vjs.zencdn.net/v/oceans.webm?sd" type="video/webm" data-res="SD" />
</video>


<video id="home_video2" controls preload="none" poster="http://img05.deviantart.net/aaee/i/2011/105/c/0/nyan_cat_wallpaper_by_nyakiru-d3e1zfl.png" width="970" height="404" class="video-js vjs-default-skin">
  <source src="http://vjs.zencdn.net/v/oceans.mp4?hd" type="video/mp4" />
</video>

<script type="text/javascript">
  vjs('home_video', {
    plugins: {
      resolutions: true
    }
  });

  vjs('home_video2', {
  });
</script>
```

From what I'm guessing video.js is attempting to reload the reolutions plugin again on the second video after some tracing. But can't get the object. I'm not 100% sure whats the best way to resolve this.

https://github.com/vidcaster/video-js-resolutions

Encase any of you are wondering. Why I don't upgrade to 5, is because I have too many websites running on the same code base.

Comment: Have you tried: https://github.com/dominic-p/videojs-resolution-selector . I think it might better handle multiple players.

Comment: Do you know if it works with Google Chrome video.js plugin? This is one of those. Better be sure about everything situations.